# Keep user after redirect with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im currently working on a side project with firebase on web and it uses user auth. I have the user logging in and then creating a game room which redirects to a separate page for the game "room". After the page redirects though i cannot pull any of the users data and the only way that im doing it is by re initializing firebase and using

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user && user != null) {
    uid = user.uid;
    email = user.email;
    currUser = user;
  } else {
    //user isnt logged in
    window.location.href = 'index.html';
  }
```

There seems to probably be an easier way to do this but i cant seem to get it working and this way also messes up sections of my other code.

Answer (score 3):

Attaching an `onAuthStateChanged` callback is the idiomatic way to get the user.

You *can* also get the user with `firebase.auth().currentUser`. But if a token refresh is required, you may in that case mis-detect that there is no user. That why an `onAuthStateChanged` callback is recommended.

See the [Firebase documentation on getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: So I have to use the onAuthStateChanged if firebase.auth().currentUser doesnt work?

Comment: I normally use `onAuthStateChanged` to update my UI for the fact that the user is signed in. I only use `firebase.auth().currentUser` in flows where I can be certain that the user is already signed in. Calling `firebase.auth().currentUser` and then checking if the result exists is an anti-pattern, in my experience that code should then be in the  `onAuthStateChanged` listener.